# Why won't the parent view controller recognize this selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a parent view controller that modally presents another view controller. When a button is pressed on the presented view controller, I need to have the parent that is presenting the view controller dismiss the presented view controller and then open up a different view controller. Here is my code after the button is pressed:

```
//Set up a reference to the parent controller 
FeedViewController* newsFeed = (FeedViewController*)self.presentingViewController;
//Tell it to dismiss the presented view controller
[newsFeed dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
//Tell it to open up the other view controller 
[newsFeed openNewsCreator];
```

The problem here is that final line. XCode says that the selector `openNewsCreator` is unrecognized by `newsFeed`. I tried setting manually giving the presented view controller a reference to the `FeedViewController` and it worked fine, so theres nothing missing in my .h file.

I even tried reversing the dismissal and presenting lines like so:

```
FeedViewController* newsFeed = (FeedViewController*)self.presentingViewController;
[newsFeed openNewsCreator];
[newsFeed dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This didn't work either. Any suggestions? Also, here's the error:

```
reason: '-[UINavigationController openNewsCreator]: unrecognized selector sent to    instance 0x9a61760'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit -- the controller you think is a FeedViewController is really a UINavigationController. That's because when you present a controller from a controller embedded in a navigation controller, it's actually the navigation controller that does the presenting, so self.presentingViewController will be the navigation controller. It's hard to tell without knowing your app's structure, but you need to get the correct reference to FeedViewController. It's probably the navigation controller's topViewController.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought this might be the problem, however when I typing in `[newsFeed openNewsCreator]`, XCode predicted that i wanted to type `openNewsCreator`, causing me to assume it had the right reference. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ByronS The compiler does that because you cast newsFeed to FeedViewController, and the complier assumes you know what you're doing, but of course, at runtime, it doesn't matter what you cast it to, it will be whatever it is.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you for the helpful information. I'll make sure not to make this mistake again.